# Can Zapier be used to send Twitter DM to new follower

Tags: twitter, zapier

Zapier has the "new follower" already set as **triger**. The question is, can the zapier java script / python "code" **action** be used to connect with Twitter API and send a DM as an action to every new follower?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

That definitely sounds possible! There's docs about the DM endpoint [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/direct-messages/sending-and-receiving/api-reference/new-event). You'll need to create a [twitter app](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/getting-started#get-started-app) to get an API key.

Zapier can't do that for ToS reasons, but as far as I know, you're free to do this!

Comment: Thanks David :-) that helps a lot!

Comment: @EladRatson can you please give me a clue on how you performed your DM for new followers ?